# Filter time range

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

We are trying to get a report as to how many tickets where logged out of hours.

Our ticketing system generates a report(which i can export to excel) giving me the "created time" of the ticket. Which is displayed as Dec 2 2018 04:11 PM.

I need to filter that to show me a time range from 5pm to 8am ( out of hours) so that I can see how many ticket where out of hours in month

Can anyone help

Thanks

Comment: Since that's not a proper Excel date, you will need to either insert a helper column to convert to a proper Excel date format or use a macro to do so. After that you can properly filter between specific ranges.

Comment: A detail sample will more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

**I would like to suggest Two different methods will help you to fix the issue.**

**Method 1:**

*This needs a **Helper Column** and then **Auto Filter**.*

[image]

1. I'm assuming that you have **Dates** in Range `A4:A13`.
2. Fill Cell `A1` with **Start Time** & Cell `A2` with **End Time**.

*(check the Time criteria in Green color).*

3. Enter this Formula in Cell `B4` & fill it Down.

   ```
    =IF(AND(A4>=$A$1,A4<=$A$2), "Good Time", "Bad Time")
   ```
4. Apply **Auto Filter to** required Range (`A4:B13`) & Filter `Good Time`.

**Method 2:**

*This is little complex but better and faster, especially when you are trying to **Filter Multiple Rows and Columns**.*

[image]

**Note:**

1. **Source Data** Range is `A4:A13`.
2. **Criteria** Cells are `A1 & A2`.
3. **Counter** is in Cell `C1`.

**Write this Formula in Cell `C1`.**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$4:$A$13>=$A$1)*($A$4:$A$13<=$A$2))
```

**Enter this Array Formula in cell `D4`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and fill it Down.**

```
{=IF(ROWS(A$4:A4)>$C$1,"",INDEX(A$4:A$13,SMALL(IF(($A$4:$A$13>=$A$1)*($A$14:$A$13<=$A$2),ROW(A$4:A$13)-ROW($A$4)+1),ROWS(A$4:A4))))}
```

*You can adjust cell references for **Criteria, Source Data, Counter and Filtered data** as your need.*

Comment: Write your concern why this has been down voted since both suggested methods are filtering DATE & TIME what OP has demanded !!